# Server 2008 Remote Apps

Tags: windows-server-2008, remoteapp, monitors

I have set up remoteapp, and according to all the documentation that i have found, the application should be able to span/move across a dual monitor setup. I found that the rdp file should include desktop span:i:1, which it does. The application comes across fine but when trying to move to secondary display the app just disappears.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I've been doing a bit of research into the issue for my own problems I've been having and found this, which should be useful:

> What kind of multi-monitor configurations are supported?
>
> Just like the requirements for usage of the /span switch in normal remote desktop, TS RemoteApp also requires the following specifications for the multi-monitor setup:
>
> - Equal resolution monitors
> - Total resolution of all monitors not exceeding 4096 x 2048
> - Top-left monitor being the primary
>
> **Any other kinds of multi-monitor configurations are not supported** with TS RemoteApp.
>
> Here are a few examples of multi-monitor setups that are unsupported:
>
> - L-shaped multi-monitor configuration
> - Unequal number of monitors on the top and bottom row (if there is a two row multi-monitor setup)
> - Center or right monitor being the primary

Source: [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/rds/archive/2007/05/07/using-terminal-services-remoteapp-programs-on-multi-monitor-client-computers.aspx)

My issue was the one about L-Shaped monitor setups, with the right-most as the default.

My guess is that your issue is likely not having the left-most monitor as primary...

Comment: Thanks worked for me too ;) Had to change monitor resolution. Ended up changing monitor to match 2nd one.

Answer (score 1):

It's been about a year since I played with this but my understanding is that spanning support is still relatively poor in the RDP Client. You need to be running at least version 6 of the RDP\MSTSC client to support spanning, both (local) monitors must be the same resolution with the primary on the left ([1] [2]) and the maximum resolution is 4096x2048. Span mode basically treats the monitors as one large display so it may not behave as you expect.

Try making the connection from the command line using: MSTSC /span /v: - this should work if both your server and client are at the right version and is less prone to typos\errors than modifying the .rdp file.

If you need more flexibility then SplitView may be worth looking at but this requires a server side component and it is commercial software. They have a very good tutorial on setting up basic spanning mode in any case so it's a good place to go if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 1):

im assuming your running XP in which case make sure you've got SP3 installed.....

To access RemoteApp programs through TS Web Access, the client computer must be running RDC 6.1. RDC 6.1 is included with the following operating systems:

```
* Windows Server 2008
* Windows Vista with Service Pack 1
* Windows XP with Service Pack 3
```

What new functionality does this feature provide?
Ability to run programs remotely

Users can run programs from a terminal server and have the same experience as if the programs were running on the end user's local computer, **including resizable windows, drag-and-drop support between multiple monitors**, and notification icons in the notification area.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753844(WS.10).aspx

hope this helps

Pete